# How to set column width in xlswriter and the same time use autofulter function?

Tags: python, filter, xlsxwriter

When I use autofilter feature of xlsxwriter in python, my column width setting doesn't work. Is there a way?

Comment: I found the error. I set first sizes for all columns and then was trying to update it. It did not work. https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/82

Answer (score 2):

Autofilters and `set_column()` should work together. The autofilter example in the docs [uses both together](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_autofilter.html) and as you can see from the image the column width is changed.

[image]

If you have an issue then you should reduce it down to the smallest code that replicates it the issue and post it.

Comment: Hi John, I found resolution here https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/82 Basically, I was trying to override sizes. Thank you for you time.